# How to add day night switcher in toolbar menu

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

[**Toolbar menu image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRJXY.jpg)

*This is the image of my toolbar Menu there are 5 icons i.e backward, forward, reload, moon symbol, and sun symbol.
now I want to add functionality to moon and sun icon i.e when the moon icon is clicked app theme changes to night mode and when sun icon is clicked the app theme. changes to day mode.*

**This is the code i have written for backward, forward and reload but now what should. i write for night mode and daymode for android app*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_previous:
            onBackPressed();
            break;


        case R.id.nav_next:
            if (webView.canGoForward()) {
                webView.goForward();
            }
            break;


        case R.id.nav_reload:
            checkConnecttion();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //Get the night mode state of the app
    int nightMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();
    case R.id.nav_previous:
        onBackPressed();
        break;


    case R.id.nav_next:
        if (webView.canGoForward()) {
            webView.goForward();
        }
        break;


    case R.id.nav_reload:
        checkConnecttion();
        break;
    
    case R.id.moon:
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        break;

    case R.id.sun:
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        break;
}

// Recreate the activity for the theme change to take effect.
recreate();

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

I suggest you to take a look at this link: [LINK](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-drawables-styles-and-themes/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#6)

It describe very well a different way to solve your problem but of course you can modify it according to your needs